# Book Identification-Mining Robots that evolve and develop emotions

Tags: story-identification

About three years ago I took one of my clients to the library for an outing and I started reading this book. I've been trying to remember the name of it every since. Please help it's really annoying me, I've googled the heck out of it and can't find it.

It's set somewhat in the future, the book starts out talking about robots they sent to an inhabitable planet to mine it for something they needed. After years and years the robots started to evolve and develop emotions and things so they shut it down or something. Not really sure how it ties into the book since I only read the first 10 or 15 pages.

In the book all of the doctors are empaths and the main character is a doctor. That's all I got.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Also you might want to update your title to contain the salient details rather than a generic as it is now.  e.g. "Book in which robots started to evolve and develop emotions", would be lot better

Comment: In case it helps they sound like von Neumann probes. See the wikipedia article for links to references in fiction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_spacecraft

Comment: Not your story, but you might also be interested in the Asimov short story "Catch that Rabbit" collected in *I, Robot*. It's broadly similar to the title of your question, if not the actual details.

Answer (score 4):

This could be ["Code of the Lifemaker"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/506194.Code_of_the_Lifemaker) by James P Hogan.

From Wikipedia:

> About 1,000,000 B.C., an unidentified alien race sent out robotic factories to many worlds in their part of the galaxy to prepare for future settlement. One of those factory ships suffers severe radiation damage from a near-miss by a supernova and goes off course, drifting in space for a hundred thousand years before landing on the Saturnian moon Titan. Due to a malfunction in its database, it begins producing imperfect copies that begin to evolve on their own.

Answer (score 1):

**The Goliath Stone** by Larry Niven and Matthew Joseph Harrington, is set in the near future (about 2028) and features nano-bots who are sent into space to mine an asteroid.  Various things go wrong, of course, and the nano-bots divide into different groups.  They do get the mining job accomplished and to deliver the metals, they invent/copy a reaction motor to bring the asteroid into near-earth orbit.

Meanwhile, the inventor of the nano-bots, Toby Glyer, is hiding out in Switzerland while illegally curing cancer.  (He has to make money to live some way.)  His former lover, May Sherbourne Wyndham (she gets really tired of Triffid jokes), has found him.  She was the last person he cured of cancer before they had to run for it.

You could call Toby a "doctor" (he *is* curing cancer) though his real passion is nano-technology.

Even if this isn't the book you're looking for, it is a fun read.